# How to translate an HTML structure to XML?

Tags: html, xml, parsing

Suppose I have HTML structured like this:

```
<div class="veggie">carrot</div>
<div class="veggie">cucumber</div>
<div class="fruit">
  <div class="citrus">orange</div>
  <div class="citrus">lemon</div>
  <div class="berry">grape</div>
</div>
<div class="veggie">lettuce</div>
<div class="dairy">milk</div>
```

But it's all on a single line like this:

```
<div class="vegetable">carrot</div><div class="vegetable">cucumber</div><div class="fruit"><div class="citrus">orange</div><div class="citrus">lemon</div><div class="berry">grape</div></div><div class="vegetable">lettuce</div><div class="dairy">milk</div>
```

How can I translate it to XML like this:

```
<veggie>carrot</veggie>
<veggie>cucumber</veggie>
<fruit>
  <citrus>orange</citrus>
  <citrus>lemon</citrus>
  <berry>grape</berry>
</fruit>
<veggie>lettuce</veggie>
<dairy>milk</dairy>
```

It sounds straightforward, but I have no clue where to start!

Comment: You need an XSLT processor and an XSL stylesheet. How are you planning to perform the transformation? What tool do you use? Are you going to write a program to do it? If so, what language?

Comment: recursively iterate building an xml string. No real magic involved.

Comment: Using what? Just any programming language? Regex?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: The HTML shown is as such well-formed XML. So this isn’t even a matter of HTML to XML conversion, but about changing (XML) markup. The principle of modification is not stated in the question, though it can be inferred from the example. There are infinitely many ways to implement such changes.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't know where to begin. I'll be using PHP once I figure out the process. The source HTML will be as well-formed as the simplified example, which is why I'm hoping this task is trivial to anyone who knows how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with regexes will be ugly and likely unreliable.  First, regexes don't handle languages with nested structures, which HTML has.  Secondly, HTML is not a clean language; it is full of errors that the browser builders in thier wisdom decided to accept, ensuring further sloppy programming by HTML writers.

A clean way to do this is to parse the HTML (just like a compiler, using a "dirty" HTML-capable parser) and build an abstract syntax tree.  (You might get away with using a browser DOM).   Then  you apply transformations to the HTML AST to incrementally convert it into XML fragments.  You can do the latter by writing  ad hoc procedural code to do a recursive tree walk, check for special cases, and spit out XML.   The procedureal is likely to look pretty ugly, because it is climbing up and down tree nodes, testing this, spitting that, all over the place, and the more specical cases you have, the messier this gets.

A *nice* way to do this is with a [program transformation system (PTS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation). A good PTS will let you define parsers and prettyprinters for (dirty) HTML and XML; you can then parse the HTML and the PTS will will an AST as suggested in the previous paragraph.    The value in the PTS is that you can usually define transformation rules using the "surface syntax" of the source and target langauges, e.g., you can say "if you see *this HTML pattern*, then replace it by *that XML* pattern.   Here's a few examples:

```
 rule replace div_class(a: attribute, t: text_content): HTMLnode -> XMLNode
  =  " <div class=\a>\t<div> "
  ->  "< \a > \t <\a /> ";
```

This rule matches the HTML AST (not text) for a div with only text content,
and maps it to an XML tag matching the class attribute, with the same text content, matching part of what OP wants.  The double-quotes are *meta* quotes, to distinguish rewrite-rule syntax from source or target language syntax.   The match-to part is written in HTML syntax with metavariable escapes \a and \t corresponding the values found that satisy the match. Note that this rule can only match HTML tags that contain *only* text as their body, because of the constraint on t.  The replacement  part generates the desired XML tag and content, substituting the values of the matched metavariables.

For the more complicated part of OP's example, where the HTML content is not just a text we need this rule:

```
 rule replace div_class(a: attribute, c: content): HTMLnode -> XMLNode
  =  " <div class=\a>\c<div> "
  ->  "< \a > \c <\a /> ";
  if  ~ match(c,text_content);
```

The \c will match anything, so that's too general, but the extra "if" constraint checks that \c is NOT text_content.  This rule will run where the previous rule will not, and vice-versa.

I think that covers all the OP's example, for the basics.

Without any other constraints, both rules will run whereever they can on the AST, and order of application for these rules don't matter.  Conceptually, each rule converts "yellow" HTML nodes to "blue" XML nodes; collectively, the rules convert all the yellow patches to blue patches.

OP probably needs additional rules to translate the other parts of the HTML document to XML in whatever way he desires; HTML being a fairly big languages, he may have to write a bunch of rules to fill this out properly.  The point is that he can write the rules largely in this same surface syntax style [as a practical matter, you often have to add some procedural code to the rules to make it all glue together right, just a lot less than the pure ad hoc way].  (Writing this as ad hoc code won't save any effort; OP will still have to handle all the HTML tag types).

Different PTS's express rules differently.  I am using the rewrite rule syntax from my own PTS [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit].   Ideally, the PTS already has available definitions of HTML and XML; DMS does.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. It's way over my head, but if no one else chimes in, I'll gladly accept your answer for its informative effort!